# How to copy elements of one pytorch tensor at given indices into another tensor without intermediate allocation or looping

Tags: python, pytorch, slice, tensor

Given

```
import torch

a: torch.Tensor
b: torch.Tensor
assert a.shape[1:] == b.shape[1:]
idx = torch.randint(b.shape[0], [a.shape[0]])
```

I want to do

```
b[...] = a[idx]
```

But without intermediate buffer produced by `a[idx]` or looping over `idx`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`torch.index_select`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.index_select.html):

```
torch.index_select(a, 0, idx, out = b)
```